# Angular2, auto update variable in multiple components

Tags: angular

I have variable "choosenModels" in my service, thats its used in two componentes: app.component and his child component gallery.component. When I click button, thats should change value of "choosenModels", but that change is only seen in his own component. How to Make it visible to other components? Here's code:

Models.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModelsService {

    private _choosenModels: string = 'female';
    _choosenModelsUpdate = new EventEmitter<string>();

    getChoosenModels() {
        return this._choosenModels;
    }
    setChoosenModels(value: string) {
        this._choosenModels = value;
        this._choosenModelsUpdate.emit(this._choosenModels);
    }
}
```

Two components, in relation parent-child. Parent App.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    providers: [ ModelsService ],
})
export class AppComponent {

    choosenModels: string = 'test';

    constructor(private _modelsService: ModelsService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.choosenModels = this._modelsService.getChoosenModels();
        this._modelsService._choosenModelsUpdate.subscribe(
            (choosenModels) => {
                this.choosenModels = this._modelsService.getChoosenModels();
            }
        );        
    }


    onChangeModelsTeamClick(value: string) {
        console.log(value);
        this._modelsService.setChoosenModels(value);
    }
}
```

App.component.html:

```
<nav class="footer__nav">
    <button
        class="button" 
        (click)="onChangeModelsTeamClick('female')"
    >
        <div class="button__description">Modelki</div>
        <i class="button__sign button__sign--female"></i>
    </button>
    <button 
       class="button button--male" 
       (click)="onChangeModelsTeamClick('male')"
    >
        <i class="button__sign button__sign--male"></i>
        <div class="button__description button__description--male">Modele</div>
    </button>
</nav>
```

Child Component: gallery.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-gallery',
    templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.scss'],
    providers: [ 
        ModelsService,
    ],
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

    choosenModels: string;    


    constructor(private _modelsService: ModelsService) {}
    ngOnInit() {

        this.choosenModels = this._modelsService.getChoosenModels();
        this._modelsService._choosenModelsUpdate.subscribe(
            (choosenModels) => {
                this.choosenModels = this._modelsService.getChoosenModels();
            }
        );        
    }

    onChangeModelsTeamClick(value: string) {
        this._modelsService.setChoosenModels(value);
    }

}
```

gallery.component.html:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <button 
        class="button" 
        (click)="onChangeModelsTeamClick('female')"
        [ngClass]="{'active': choosenModels=='female'}" 
    >
        MODELKI
    </button><!--
 --><button 
        class="button"
        (click)="onChangeModelsTeamClick('male')"
        [ngClass]="{'active': choosenModels=='male'}" 
    >
        MODELE
    </button><!--
 --><button 
        class="button"
        (click)="onChangeModelsTeamClick('premium')"
        [ngClass]="{'active': choosenModels=='premium'}" 
    >
        PREMIUM
    </button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
providers: [ 
    ModelsService,
]
```

This tells Angular to create a ModelsService instance dedicated to each f that component instance (and their child components, recursively). Since both of your components have that, they each have their own instance of the service.

Other problems:

- `choosen` should be `chosen`
- don't use EventEmitter in a service. This should be used for a component Output only. Use an RxJS subject.
- you don't even need any event anyway: you could simply use a getter on your component that returns the value stored in the service directly, instead of having three copies of the same information in 3 different places.